# Android 2D scrolling Listview?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-listview, android-view, android-gridview

I would like to create a ListView widget which allowed scrolling horizontally within a row.  I've seen a similar thing in the UK Sky+ app on the grid channel view.

The list will represent hours in the day (vertical) divided into 5 mins timeslots (Horizontal)

```
Scroll
^
|
| 08:00 | 08:05 | 08:10 | 08:15 | .... -> Scroll
| 09:00 | 09:05 | 09:10 | 09:15 | .... -> Scroll
|
v
Scroll
```

Each "cell" should be able to have a background colour to identify if the time is available (greyed out type functionality for unavailable).

Each "cell" should be able to accept a touch event and change cell colour on touch.  Only one cell (time) can be selected.

I could place a large tableview in a scrollView I suppose, but not ideal.
It's not quite a gallery either as it won't contain images and I want the contents to be structured, not auto wrapped etc.

Thanks for any pointers

Martin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Horizontal list view, which have all the functionalities of a normal ListView widget.

[This Link Will Help You](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34)

I tried the implementation and it worked fine for me.

Comment: I've created a test project using the HorizontalListView widget you linked.  Call me stupid (shhh) but I can only get a single row scrolling horizontally, I want vertical and horizontal scrolling.  I'm sure I'm doing something daft, not sure what though.  I've hooked up an adapter with 3xString[] arrays and I'm getting my  ListItem view repeated 3x on a single row rather than 3 rows each containing my ListItem view.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. If you have 3 rows, try adding 3 horizontal listviews into a vertical scrollview.